# Cannot debug - variables values not displayed

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, ios9, xcode7

So, I'm currently working on pretty large project, which also consists of iOS application. Problem is, that few days ago, Xcode debugger stopped displaying variable values. I've tried to reset build settings, checked code optimization, enabled/disabled bitcode, tried older git commits, sadly with no luck. Also I've reinstalled Xcode, tried it on different systems, also installed El Capitan, to make sure, it's not some compatibility issue regarding Xcode 7 and Yosemite.

As you can see on the screen, when i try to print variable description, it displays error "Unable to determine byte size."
[image: no variable displayed]

Could this be a bug? 
Application so far targets only iOS 9, so I wasn't able to test it on any non beta software.

Comment: post your code my friend

Comment: What specific part of code you need? Debugging doesn't work anywhere in the project and as you surely understand I cannot post bigger parts of code.

Comment: Have you tried the `print` lldb command? If so, what happens?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've came up with at least semi functional solution, it is now working only on physical device, on simulator I'm still not able to debug. 
What I did is, that I've set optimization level both on release and debug to "Fastest/smallest [-Os]" which doesn't make any sense, but it is working, so it's fine with me.